# TypeError exception when calling React function

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am refactoring a small app that organises books onto respective shelves. I have extracted the `JSX` into a `Book.js` file to handle rendering each book object and call the `updateShelf` method to move books between shelves.

To that end, I have exported the `updateShelf` function from `App.js` and imported it into the `Book.js` component which is embedded in the `ListBooks` which uses the `map` function to pass each book object to `Book` to be rendered.

The issue I have is that when the `onChange` handler in `Book` fires I get the below exception:

`TypeError: Object(...) is not a function`

```
  17 | <div className="book-top">
  18 |     <div className="book-cover" style={{ width: 128, height: 193, backgroundImage: `url(${book.imageLinks.thumbnail})` }}></div>
  19 |         <div className="book-shelf-changer"> 
> 20 |             <select value={book.shelf} onChange={(e) => updateShelf(book, e.target.value)}>
  21 |                 <option value="none" disabled >Move to...</option>
  22 |                 <option value="currentlyReading" >Currently Reading</option>
  23 |                 <option value="wantToRead" >Want to Read</option>
```

I am not sure what it is that I am doing wrong.

I've included quite a lot because I'm not sure exactly where the issue issue's source is. Let me know if I need to trim down the post.

`App.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ListBooks from './ListBooks'
import SearchBooks from './SearchBooks'
import * as BooksAPI from './utils/BooksAPI'
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom'

class BooksApp extends Component {
  state = {
    books: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    BooksAPI.getAll()
    .then((books) => {
      this.setState(() => ({
        books
      }))
    })
  }

  updateShelf(book, shelf) {
    this.state.books.forEach(b => {
      if(b.id === book.id && shelf !== '' && shelf !== 'none') {
        b.shelf = shelf
        this.setState((currentState) => ({
          books: currentState.books
        }))
        BooksAPI.update(book, shelf)
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Route exact path='/' render={() => (
          <ListBooks
          books={this.state.books}
          onUpdateShelf={this.updateShelf}
          />
        )} />
        <Route exact path='/search' render={() => (
          <SearchBooks
          books={this.state.books}
          />
        )} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default BooksApp
export const updateShelf = updateShelf;
```

`ListBooks.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import './App.css'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import Book from './Book'

const shelves = [
  {
    key: 'currentlyReading',
    name: 'Currently Reading'
  },
  {
    key: 'wantToRead',
    name: 'Want To Read'
  },
  {
    key: 'read',
    name: 'Read'
  }
];

class ListBooks extends Component {

    static propTypes = {
       books: PropTypes.array.isRequired
    }

    render() {

        const { books } = this.props

        function getBooksForShelf(shelfKey) {
          return books.filter(book => book.shelf === shelfKey);
        }

        return(
            <div className="app">
              <div className="list-books">
                <div className="list-books-title">
                  <h1>My Reads</h1>
                </div>
                <div className="list-books-content">
                  <div>
                    { shelves.map((shelf) => (
                      <div key={shelf.key} className="bookshelf">
                        <h2 className="bookshelf-title">{shelf.name}</h2>
                          <div className="bookshelf-books">
                            <ol className="books-grid">
                        <li>
                          { getBooksForShelf(shelf.key).map((book) => (
                            <Book key={book.id} book={book}/>
                            ))}
                          </li>
                        </ol>
                        </div> 
                      </div>
                    )) }
                  </div>
                </div>
                <Link
                    to='/search'
                    className="open-search">
                    Find a Book
                </Link>
              </div>
            }
          </div>
        )
    }
}

export default ListBooks
```

`Book.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { updateShelf } from './App'

class Book extends Component {

    static propTypes = {
        book: PropTypes.object.isRequired
    }    

    render() {

        const { book } = this.props

        return(
            <div key={book.id} className="book">
                <div className="book-top">
                    <div className="book-cover" style={{ width: 128, height: 193, backgroundImage: `url(${book.imageLinks.thumbnail})` }}></div>
                        <div className="book-shelf-changer"> 
                            <select value={book.shelf} onChange={(e) => updateShelf(book, e.target.value)}>
                                <option value="none" disabled >Move to...</option>
                                <option value="currentlyReading" >Currently Reading</option>
                                <option value="wantToRead" >Want to Read</option>
                                <option value="read" >Read</option>
                                <option value="none" >None</option>
                            </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                     <div className="book-title">{book.title}</div>
                <div className="book-authors">{book.authors}</div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Book
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're exporting `export const updateShelf = updateShelf`. But `updateShelf` is a part of the Component, so it's most likely undefined. You should move the method outside of the class if you plan to export it, or pass it down as a prop if you expect it to change the component.

Comment: That did the job. I had to pass it via ListBooks.js component though. Is there a way to pass it direct to Book.js?

Comment: You can use the React Context API. But I would recommend passing it through ListBooks.js for now.